# Question's number of Views dropping

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign, views

Hi everyone,

I asked  [a question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3851730/maths-in-programming-the-developers-guide) yesterday and noticed the number of views dropped by about half randomly.

I had my profile on my laptop open from yesterday, when the Views Count was at 519.

[image: Number of Views]

Today, it has dropped to 380. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3851730/maths-in-programming-the-developers-guide).

**Is this normal?**

Comment: I've seen things on the internet I wish I could unsee -- maybe someone finally figured out how to do it?

Comment: @Jim - +1 Agreed  ...thinking Human Centipede

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were some errors with view counts over the weekend.

Basically, pretty much everything ended up with an inflated view count total.  On so, the margin was about 40% (on average).

This has been corrected, and that's what you see there.

Comment: So I'm not imagining things. This is good news.